# Kiali: Avoid KIA1106 - More than one Virtual Service for same host

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kiali, istio-kiali

I'm using Kiali on Istio/Kubernetes to monitor my mesh.

I need to route 2 different pods based in URL contain, and for this, I'm following the tutorial in [Split large virtual services and destination rules into multiple resources](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/#split-virtual-services). So, I created 2 VirtualServices for the same host and gateway:

Service 1:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vs-product-composite
spec:
  hosts:
  - "kubernetes.b-thinking.com"
  gateways:
  - gw-ingress
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /product-composite
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: product-composite
```

Service 2:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: uaa
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: uaa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: uaa
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: uaa
        image: bthinking/uaa
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT
          value: DEBUG
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8090
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 350Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: uaa
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: uaa
  ports:
    - port: 8090
      nodePort: 31090
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vs-auth
spec:
  hosts:
  - "kubernetes.b-thinking.com"
  gateways:
  - gw-ingress
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /oauth
    rewrite:
      uri: "/uaa/oauth"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8090
        host: uaa
```

But, I'm getting the warning `KIA1106 - More than one Virtual Service for same host`

Looking in [docs](https://kiali.io/documentation/latest/validations/#_kia1106_more_than_one_virtual_service_for_same_host), it explain the case (it's my case), but it redirect to the same guide I have followed.

Comment: I believe it's just a warning. It's clear that it's your intention to have more then one `VirtualService` for the same host.

Comment: Hello, please try to create 2 separate gateways (they can have the same configuration but they need to have different names) and let me know if this warning still shows.